# Any way to PGP encrypt data stream and save it directly to the FTP without having to save it locally?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, sftp, pgp

I have to send PGP encrypted file in asc format to FTP folder via sFTP. Is there a way to PGP encrypt a stream (which is CSV formatted stream) and push it to the sFTP **without having to save it on local machine**.

Below is the function I use for PGP encryption which takes file name as param:

```
Private Function PGPEncrypt(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
        Dim errorHappened As Boolean = False
        Dim encodedFileName As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", FileName, ".asc")
        Dim pgpRecipient As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PgpRecipient")
        Dim psi As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        Dim ErrorResult As String = ""
        Dim Result As String = ""
        Try
            psi = New ProcessStartInfo(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PgpPath"))
            psi.CreateNoWindow = True
            psi.UseShellExecute = False
            psi.Arguments = String.Format(" --armor --yes --recipient ""{0}"" --output ""{1}"" --encrypt ""{2}""", _
                                          pgpRecipient, encodedFileName, FileName)
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = True
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            psi.RedirectStandardError = True
            ProcessPGP = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
            ProcessPGP.StandardInput.Write(m_Passphrase)
            Result = ProcessPGP.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
            ProcessPGP.WaitForExit()
        Catch ex As Exception
            errorHappened = True
            Dim ReadError As New StringBuilder()
            ReadError.Append(vbCrLf & "Error Detail:")
            ReadError.Append(vbCrLf & ex.ToString())
            OurEventLog.WriteEntry(ReadError.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
        Return errorHappened
    End Function
```

Again, the main requirement is **not** to save the PGP encrypted file locally and then send to FTP but PGP encrypted file must be created through a stream.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

FTP Code:

```
 ftp.ConnectMode = FTPConnectMode.PASV
                ftp.RemoteHost = Csla.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FTPRemoteHost")
                If _blnDiagnostics Then DiagnosticsManager.Publish("STREAM_TO_FTP: CONNECT TO FTP", DiagnosticsManager.EntryType.SuccessAudit)
                ftp.Connect()
                ftp.Login(strUser, strPassword)
                ftp.TransferType = FTPTransferType.BINARY 'ASCII
                ftp.Put(OUTBOUNDMESSAGE, pFilename)

                ftp.Quit()
                ftp = Nothing
```

OUTBOUNDMESSAGE is the System.IO.Stream.

Comment: That doesn't look like C# to me...?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the filename as an option on the command line, you can pass `-` to `--output` which directly exposes the output to the console. You can stream this data directly.

Your `Arguments` property would then look like this:

```
psi.Arguments = String.Format(" --armor --yes --recipient ""{0}"" --output - --encrypt ""{1}""", _
                                      pgpRecipient, FileName)
```

When you execute the process, `ProcessPGP.StandardOutput` should yield the stream you need.

Comment: What about FTP component? Just send this encrypted data stream to FTP and save it as asc?

Comment: Since you didn't include any code of how you're sending the data over FTP, I cannot say for sure what you would do. If you have to stream your existing file over FTP, then it is simply a matter of using the output stream instead. If it's a library that takes a file in as an argument and does the streaming work itself, then you'll need to find an FTP library that does support taking in some form of `Stream`.

Comment: Added code for FTP. I use ftp.Put which takes stream as parameter. So, basically you mean PGP encrypt the stream and save it as asc on ftp?

Comment: You can use the `ProcessPGP.StandardOutput.BaseStream` property in place of the `OUTBOUNDMESSAGE` variable you have in your added code.